# How to get a logged user Id in a WebService

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a method that i call in my web service called `Correct()` - whenever a user gets something correct, I call this method and increment `GameInfo.correct`.  In this method I want to also increment the logged on users counter attribute.

```
public void Correct()
{
    GameInfo.correct++;

    The_Factory_Chante.Models.Learner learner;
    using (The_Factory_Chante.Models.The_FactoryDBContext db2 = new The_Factory_Chante.Models.The_FactoryDBContext())
    {
        learner = db2.Learners.ToList().FirstOrDefault(a => a.learnerID == User.Identity.GetUserId());
        learner.counter++;
    }
}
```

However i get the following error:

> 'System.Security.Principal.IIdentity' does not contain a definition for 'GetUserId' and no extension method 'GetUserId' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Security.Principal.IIdentity' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What are you using to authenticate users?  Is this a WebAPI or similar?

Comment: User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

Comment: Yes, but are you using something like ASPNet.Identity?  What made you use `GetUserId()`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Asp.Net Identity you must add the following:

```
using System.Web.Security;
```

Then you will be able to use

```
User.Identity.GetUserId()
```